Undefined constant errors after Rails 7 upgrade with class names containing part of modules
After upgrading my gem to Rails 7, I am seeing a lot of undefined constants errors.
For example:
app/models/my_gem/api/irr_item.rb
module MyGem
  module Api
    class IrrItem < MyGem::Api::ApplicationRecord

When making IRR uppercase in my class, it fixes the issue:
module MyGem
  module Api
    class IRRItem < MyGem::Api::ApplicationRecord

Or another situation:
app/constraints/graphiql_route_constraint.rb
class GraphiqlRouteConstraint

When making QL uppercase in my class, it fixes the issue:
class GraphiQLRouteConstraint

I fixed all my issues by uppercasing these but I don't understand why.  Is it because I have a module called IRR somewhere and now it needs to be uppercase all the time?

My guess is that you have an acronym inflection set up for IRR.  Try 'irr_item'.camelize.  As for why this worked in classic that is a good question but the way it monkeypatched constant missing and looked up constants was kind of insane.

In classic, the input of the autoloader was the name of the missing constant, "IrrItem". The autoloader underscored it, "irr_item", and looked up the file in the file system.
Zeitwerk works the other way around. The input of the autoloader is the file name, and assumes "irr_item".camelize is the constant defined there. As @max said, looks like the application has acronyms defined.
I guess it would be nice that the acronyms are used across all their instances. But to unblock this quickly you could hard-code inflections for these special cases:
# config/initializers/zeitwerk.rb

# IRR and GraphQL are defined as acronyms, but we have
# some classes whose names do not take them into account.
# If they get ever renamed, please remove this configuration.

main = Rails.autoloaders.main
main.inflector.inflect(
  "irr_item" => "IrrItem",
  "graphiql_route_constraint" => "GraphiqlRouteConstraint"
)

Please check out these docs for further details.
See also the guide Classic to Zeitwerk HOWTO for more stuff that may show up in the migration.
